# Design pattern for creating similar but different classes

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns

I have a main-class that takes a list of sources and returns two objects for each source; one with the required data and one analytics tool.

The `Analytics`-class has different methods depending on what source it is. The `Data`-class extracts data from different paths and cleans the data in different ways depending on the source. Importing/exporting is made through pandas `read_excel()`. The analytics tool outputs some calculations based on what source the data comes from.

```
class Main_class():
    def __init__(self, sources = ['a','b','c']):
        self.data_sources = {}
        self.analytics = {}
        for s in sources:
            self.data_sources[s] = Data(s)
            self.analytics[s] = Analytics(s, self.data_sources[s])
```

Right now, my solution is to have one `Data`-class and one `Analytics`-class which has `if`-statements to adapt the functionality of the class depending on the source. This is not a scalable or otherwise good solution, I basically have checks **in both classes** where I say

```
acceptable_sources = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if source not in acceptable_sources: 
    raise ValueError(f"Only acceptable sources are: {acceptable_sources}")
```

Then, I need more checks to set the `self.variables` correctly, here's an example from the `Data`-class

```
self.data = {}
if source == 'a': # if it's a, then there's 3 sources
    self.data[a] = pd.read_excel('a_1.xlsx')
    self.data[a] = pd.read_excel('a_2.xlsx')
    self.data[a] = pd.read_excel('a_2.xlsx')
elif source == 'b': # if it's b, then there's 2 sources
    self.data[a] = pd.read_excel('b_1.xlsx')
    self.data[a] = pd.read_excel('b_2.xlsx')
```

This is problematic, since there will be a lot of `if`-statements as the number of sources increase, but it might be the best solution, I'm not sure. Using the same idea in my Analytics-class, there will be a lot of unused functions for each source-case. Let's say there are 30 functions for source `a`, 25 functions for source `b` and 40 functions for source `c`. Some of these functions might be shared across sources, and some will be unique. So whichever source I use, there will be a lot of unused methods which seems like a waste.

My first thought was to make `Analytics` and `Data` into abstract classes and create unique classes for each compatible source, but then I wouldn't be able to instantiate them in the `for`-loop in my main class. Then I thought that I could include them in a `Class_holder` which basically checks which class I want to instantiate, and if it exists to return an object of that class. So for example if I have X possible sources, the `Class_holder` would be able to handle and return X different classes, and if it doesn't exist return an error. It would look something like

```
from analytics import A, B, C # classes I should create with correct methods
class Class_holder:
    def __init__(self, source, data):
        self.acceptable_sources = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        if source in acceptable_sources: 
            raise ValueError(f"Only acceptable sources are: {acceptable_sources}")
        self.source = source
        self.data = data

    def return_analytics_class(self):
        if self.source == 'a':
            return A(self.data)
        elif self.source == 'b':
            return B(self.data)
        elif self.source == 'c':
            return C(self.data)
```

And the classes I have called `A`, `B`, `C` could either be a combination of `Data` and `Analytics`, or I could separate it by having one `Data` and one `Analytics`-class for each source, then the `Class_holder.return_class()` would return a tuple with two classes. For the `Class_holder`-solution I would have to change my `Main` to something like

```
from a_file import Data
from another_file import Class_holder
class Main_class():
    def __init__(self, sources = ['a','b','c'])
        self.data_sources = {}
        for s in sources:
            self.data_souces[s] = Data(s)
        self.analytics = {}
        for s in sources:
            self.analytics[s] = Class_holder(s, self.data_sources[s]).return_analytics_class()
```

But then I'm back to my original problem, where I need to have checks in both `Data` and `Class_holder` to see if the sources are compatible, however this might solve the problem of only instantiating the correct analytics-functions for each source.

It just doesn't feel like an optimal way of doing this kind of task, so I'm turning to codereview to ask for a bit of guidance, if you know any design pattern or other solution for this kind of problem, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that you are using Python 3.6 ore newer, I would use abstract base classes and use the `__init_subclass__()` method to automatically register new subclasses and the sources they handle.  A classmethod on the baseclass can then look up the appropriate subclass based on the source.

If the decision on which subclass to use is more complicated, each subclass can have a `can_you_handle(self, source)` method that returns True if is can handle the source.  The base class `from_source()` method calls `can_you_handle()` on each subclass until it finds one that can handle the source.

Here's a base class:

```
class Data:
    registry = {}
    
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source

    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        for source in cls.sources:
            if source not in Data.registry:
                Data.registry[source] = cls
                
            else:
                other_cls = Data.registry[source].__name__
                message = f"class '{other_cls}' already registered for source '{source}'."
                raise ValueError(message)

        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
            
        
    @classmethod
    def from_source(self, source):
        try:
            cls = Data.registry[source]
            return cls(source)
        
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(f"Unkown source: {source}") from None
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}('{self.source}')"
```

Some subclasses:

```
class Data_A(Data):
    sources = 'a','b'
    
    def method_for_source_A(self):
        print('doing something with Data_A')
    
class Data_C(Data):
    sources = 'c','d','e'

    def method_for_source_C(self):
        print('doing something with Data_C')
```

Check the registry was populated:

```
print(Data.registry)
```

prints:

```
{'a': __main__.Data_A, 'b': __main__.Data_A, 'c': __main__.Data_C,
 'd': __main__.Data_C, 'e': __main__.Data_C}
```

Try it out:

```
data = Data.from_source('b')
print(f"{str(data)} using {data.source}")

data = Data.from_source('e')
print(f"{str(data)} using {data.source}")

data = Data.from_source('q')
print(f"{str(data)} using {data.source}")
```

prints:

```
Data_A('b') using b
Data_C('e') using e
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-072d12d66274> in <module>
      5 print(f"{str(data)} using {data.source}")
      6 
----> 7 data = Data.from_source('q')
      8 print(f"{str(data)} using {data.source}")

<ipython-input-70-bd84ab43455a> in from_source(self, source)
     20 
     21         except KeyError:
---> 22             raise ValueError(f"Unkown source: {source}") from None
     23 
     24     def __str__(self):

ValueError: Unkown source: q
```

Try defining a subclass with a duplicated source:

```
class Data_F(Data):
    sources = 'f','e'

    def method_for_source_F(self):
        print('doing something with Data_F')
```

result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-39d1c8d7edf7> in <module>
----> 1 class Data_F(Data):
      2     sources = 'f','e'
      3 
      4     def method_for_source_F(self):
      5         print('doing something with Data_F')

<ipython-input-120-08031ccf6700> in __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs)
     14                 other_cls = Data.registry[source].__name__
     15                 message = f"class '{other_cls}' already registered for source '{source}'."
---> 16                 raise ValueError(message) from None
     17 
     18         super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

ValueError: class 'Data_C' already registered for source 'e'.
```

`class Analytics` would be handled in an analogous manner.

Your main class would then look like this:

```
class Main_class():
    def __init__(self, sources = ['a','b','c']):
        self.data_sources = {}
        self.analytics = {}

        for s in sources:
            data = Data.from_source(s)
            self.data_sources[s] = data

            analytic = Analytics.from_source(s)
            self.analytics[s] = analytic(data)
```

One more thing, `__init_subclass__()` takes keyword arguments.  So you could write the code above like this (I just prefer using class variables as shown above):

```
    def __init_subclass__(cls, sources, **kwargs):   # changed this line
        for source in sources:                       # and this one
            if source not in Data.registry:
                Data.registry[source] = cls
                
            else:
                other_cls = Data.registry[source].__name__
                message = f"class '{other_cls}' already registered for source '{source}'."
                raise ValueError(message)

        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
```

And then the subclasses would look like this:

```
class Data_A(Data, sources=('a','b')):   # source in now a keyword argument
    
    def method_for_source_A(self):
        print('doing something with Data_A')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for helping out! You've used a lot of things I haven't seen before, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner/14605349#14605349) answer helped me understand some of it. I'll definitely study and use this, and I'll probably look into using more inheritance between classes, for example if classes B,C,D has 3 shared functions, maybe they could inherit from class A which has these functions predefined (assuming that classes A,B,C,D are all subclasses to Data).

Comment: I was going to mention using "mixins" as a way to refactor common features from Data subclasses, but the answer was rather long already.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it atleast, I hadn't heard of mixins before so I'll definitely check it out. And if I have any questions I'll create a new ticket for it.